# why is my mouse doing weird stuff when i'm coding ? (flickering? blinking, maybe?)

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

I'm sorry since English is not my first language : and since I can't even describe what's going on in my native language, this is going to be complicated.

I'm coding a website and everything was ok so far. But at some point, I attached a link to an image and used `hover` in css so the picture "shines" when the cursor is on it. The only problem I have is that, when the mouse is on the picture it kinda "panics?" and starts to changing from normal mouse to the pointing finger really quickly. I also struggle to be able to click on the picture when this happens. (I'm on macOS Monterey 12.2 btw)

Since I know I explained that terribly, here's a [YT Video showing my problem.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dR5ho5AwArM)

Thank you and sorry again for the whacky English.

Edit 1: Ok so I'm using Brave Browser, and this problem doesn't happen on Safari when I tried it on there, so I really don't know if it's my browser being weird and if I can fix this in any way

Comment: Could you show the CSS, both before hover and during hover.

Comment: [there you go](https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/51890590736_bba1a7ebe3_c.jpg) and, just in case, [here's the HTML as well](https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/51890590726_871ec523c7_k.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by opacity: 10? And please put code, not images of code, direct into your question. Thanks.